# How to access the variable in the method of other class in java

Tags: java, oop

1st class

```
public class component {
public static void setComponents(JPanel panel) {
    panel.setLayout(null);
    JLabel userLabel = new JLabel("User ID");
    userLabel.setBounds(10,20,80,25);
    panel.add(userLabel);
    JLabel passwordLabel = new JLabel("Password");
    passwordLabel.setBounds(10,50,80,25);
    panel.add(passwordLabel);
    JTextField textfield = new JTextField(20);
    textfield.setBounds(100,20,180,25);
    panel.add(textfield);
    JPasswordField password = new JPasswordField();
    password.setBounds(100,50,180,25);
    panel.add(password);
    JButton loginButton = new JButton("Login");
    loginButton.setBounds(100,100,100,25);
    panel.add(loginButton);
    loginButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
    panel.add(loginButton);

}
```

2nd Class

```
public class ButtonListener extends component  implements ActionListener {
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource()==loginButton)
}
```

}

The problem is in loginButton at 2nd class.
ERROR: can't resolve symbol 'loginButton' appears.
I am unable to access the loginButton in the method of first class. I have tried different methods 
but couldn't resolve it.

Comment: You have to use instance variables/methods(maybe a constructor) for this. Also, class names are written PascalCase by convention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a quick prototyping you can define `JButton loginButton` as a class field, in this way you can access it from your other classes. For example:

```
public class component {
    public static JButton loginButton = new JButton("Login");
    public static void setComponents(JPanel panel) {
    ...
    }
}
```